# Can we set DSCP runtime in ip header using thrift library

Tags: thrift

I have a query on thrift library. I am running a thrift server which can accept connections from clients over sockets. I have a requirement to set the DSCP value in the ip header for the messages from server to clients. I understand we can use setsockopt on the socket, once the incoming connection is accepted by using setAcceptCallback, however the DSCP in my case can be configurable and can change at any moment. I havent seen any interface from thrift library which can expose the sockets to be able to set the option in run time. Is there a way i can resolve this?